# Need a way to write custom metrics in my flink program

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I need to know the way to implement custom metrics in my flink program.
Currently, I know we can create custom metrics with the help of RuntimeContext. 
But in my aggregate() I do not have RuntimeContext. I am using window operator and applying aggregate() method on it. And I am passing AggregateFunction in aggregate() method.

So, Kindly guide me, how can I create custom metrics in my code?

Note: As we know we can not user RichAggregateFunction with aggregate() method

Comment: Could you explain why you can not use RichAggregateFunction? To define metrics, you need to have access to some core resources of flink, and the only way to do that is through RichFuncion#getRuntimeContext

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to update a metric with every element, I think you'll have to implement a custom window operator in which you override the open and processElement methods.

It's not generally recommended to get involved in the operator internals, but sometimes it's the only way to get access to interfaces you need that are otherwise hidden.